# php foreach combine 2 array into 1 row (workdays & data)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a problem with my current "Attendance Project", so I have 2 arrays.

- 1st array is to show a "workdays"
  the 1st array show only workdays in current month ex:April, so the result in my 1st array is (3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21,24,25,26,27,28)
- 2nd array is showing Employee Attendance in current month ex:April, so the result in my 2nd array is (17, 19)

here is my current code :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 200px">Siswa</th>
            <!-- <?php for($i = 1; $i < 31; ++$i){?>
            <th><?= $i ?></th>
            <?php } ?> -->
            <?php foreach($workdays as $w){ ?>
            <th><?=$w;?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        // for($x = 1; $x < 27; ++$x){
        foreach($records as $r){
        ?>
        <tr>
<td style="width: 200px"><?=$r->StudentName;?></td>
<?php
    ?>
    <?php 
         foreach($workdays as $w){
           foreach($tanggale as $t){ 

            if($w == $t){
            ?>
                <td style="background: #FFF000">M</td>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <td style="background: #48C9A9">O</td>
                <?php } } } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php }  ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It will produce :
[image]

I want value (17 and 19) will markup the data with yellow background, and the table is NOT out of range.
Any help will appreciate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems messy and I'm not gonna try to fix it on what you have, but I'll suggest solution:

1st - run foreach ($workdays as $w) and make header
2nd - run foreach ($workdays as $w) and make table-body like:

```
foreach ($workdays as $w) {
    if (in_array($w, $tanggale)) //if tanggle is the one with 17 and 19
    {
         //code
    }
    else
    {
         //code
    }
}
```

Comment: your foreach loop nested in foreach loop must be making that "out of range" part because it runs loop * loop times

Answer (score 0):

Simply what u can do is combine the 2 arrays in to one and then iterate the combine array as per your requirment.
Check below code for combining the array

```
<?php
    $working_days = array(3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21,24,25,26,27,28);
    $present_days = array(17.19);
    $combine_attendence_array = array();
    foreach($working_days as $day) {
    $combine_attendence_array[$day] = 'Absent';
        if(in_array($day, $present_days)) {
            $combine_attendence_array[$day] = 'Present';
        }
    }
?>
```

This code will create combine array with key as day and value is present or Absent.

Now you can iterate as per your requirement below is the iteration code.

```
foreach($combine_attendence_array as $day => $value){
            if($value == 'Present'){  ?>
                <td style="background: #FFF000">M</td>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <td style="background: #48C9A9">O</td>
                <?php }     ?>
                <?php }    ?>
```

I hope this answers solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way

```html
<?php 
        foreach($tanggale as $t){ 
            
            if(in_array($t,$workdays)){
            ?>
                <td style="background: #FFF000">M</td>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <td style="background: #48C9A9">O</td>
                <?php } }  ?>
        </tr>
        <?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($workdays as $w){
   foreach($tanggale as $t){
       if($w == $t){
          $color = "#FFF000";
          $text = "M";
       } else {
          $color = "#48C9A9";
          $text = "O";
       }
   }
       ?>
       <td style="background: <?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></td>


<?php }?>
```